# Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

Tags: docker, vagrant

Problem: I am trying to run docker inside vagrant, my Vagrantfile contains following:-

```
  config.vm.provision "docker" do |d|
     d.run "ubuntu",
       cmd: "bash -l",
       args: "-v '/vagrant:/var/www'"
  end
```

docker gets installed but when I run any command it gives the error below:-

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

I have tried

1. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E52668_01/E75728/html/section_rdz_hmw_2q.html
2. logged in as `root` into vagrant and started docker still same problem.
3. tried `chmod on /var/run/docker.sock` file

nothing seems to work.

output of `ps -ef` is

```
/usr/bin/dockerd

docker-containerd -l unix:///var/run/docker/libcontainerd/docker-containerd.sock --metrics-interval=0 --start-timeout 2m --state-dir 
/var/run/docker/libcontainerd/containerd --shim docker-containerd-shim --runtime docker-runc
```

Comment: make sure docker service is running or else start it by : sudo service docker start .
then try adding sudo to the run command you are executing

Answer (score 23):

Here is what happened to me and what could be a possible solution for someone else. I'm running on **Ubuntu 16.04**.

I ultimately purged and reinstalled everything from the **docker-ce** install. I mean everything. Still not working...

Through my internet wizardry I was able to find an article (I can't recall where, there were so many) mentioning that the file located at:

**`$ sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/docker.service`**

Had a -d in the place of the daemon at Execstart. That wasn't the case for me. I had ...daemon -D..., but I did notice that it was pointing to **/usr/bin/local/docker**. That didn't exist, but what does exist is **/usr/bin/docker**. In that location you will also find docker-containerd, dockerd, etc...

Anyway, I made the change to the docker.service file--simply dropping **/local** out of there. Saved. Then:

```
$ systemctl daemon-reload
$ sudo service docker restart
$ sudo service docker status (should see active (running))
$ sudo docker run hello-world
```

Success!

Comment: Your first paragraph here isn't really very 'StackOverflow'-y. Although I'd agree that those sort of answers are annoying in other forums, albeit often the correct solution - too many people just post questions online without attempting to interpret the error message they're seeing - that doesn't happen so much on StackOverflow, and, if people do give those answers, that's what the downvote button is for.

Answer (score 6):

On your ssh server, run:

1. `systemctl start docker`
2. `systemctl status docker`

Docker will start on the server and have a socket on its respective.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue, running the command `sudo service docker restart`, followed by restarting the docker image fixed the issue for me

Answer (score 0):

Start docker deamon by
systemctl start docker.service

Be sure to run command as superuser

Answer (score 0):

i've gotten the same error response. when i checkout the daemon.json file, and i found that

```
{
     "registry-mirrors": ["http://hub-mirror.c.163.com"]
     "graph": "/etc/docker/mirror"
}
```

as you can see, i missed  ","  so i corrected it so simple. how careless i was!

```
{
     "registry-mirrors": ["http://hub-mirror.c.163.com"],
     "graph": "/etc/docker/mirror"
}
```

sometimes you need check your code carefully

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to do:

```
sudo rm /var/run/docker.pid
sudo docker start [my_container]
```