# Minor Docker build issue

Tags: docker

This isn't that big of a deal, but I build (on an up-to-date Mac) quite often and something like one time out of ten I get an error like that shown below.  Running with `--debug` or `--stacktrace` is of no avail as the build ALWAYS works by simply re-running.

Anyone know what might be wrong?

```
Error response from daemon: no active session for e431bb06cd5af92b929085ed1acf1dd1e07907e458f11f5ed622a4d8400403cb: context deadline exceeded

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':docker:my-product-name:my-project-name:docker'.
> Process 'command 'docker'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

**Update per comments**

The error occurs when running a gradle build against the product.  This build is several years old - passed through many versions of both gradle (currently 3.5) and docker (currently 18.06).  I do not use this build alone - many others do as well.  This error is transitory.  It occurs with a low frequency, say one out of every ten to twenty builds.  Simply re-running the build always results in success - hence my statement that "this isn't that big of a deal...."

Comment: What are you try to do here, please provide more details and dockerfile

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43401645/cannot-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-at-unix-var-run-docker-sock-is-the-docke/45125251#45125251
This might help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case it helps anyone, this error seems to occur when the images being built near the max "Disk image size" set on Docker->Preferences->Disk tab.   Increasing that limit or doing a `docker image prune` command seems to avoid the error.

Comment: the prune fixed the problem for me very quick, thanks for saving me potentially hours!